# Can Z3 handle datatypes that contains sorts introduced by declare-sort/define-sort?

Tags: z3

I'm trying to define a datatype that contains sorts introduced by declare-sort or define-sort.
But the following attempt results in errors.

```
(declare-sort A)
(define-sort B () Int)
(declare-datatypes ((listA (nilA) (consA (hdA A) (tlA listA))))) ;=> unknown sort 'A'
(declare-datatypes ((listB (nilB) (consB (hdB B) (tlB listB))))) ;=> unknown sort 'B'
```

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can. BTW, it seems you are using an old version of Z3.
You should try the latest version.
Z3 3.x supports parametric types. So, the syntax for declaring datatypes changed a little bit.
Now, you have to write:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((listA (nilA) (consA (hdA A) (tlA listA)))))
```

In the new syntax, you can specify type parameters. Since listA is not parametric, you just provided the empty list `()` of type parameters.
For more information about datatypes in Z3, consult the [Z3 guide](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/guide).

Using parametric types, you can also encode `listA` and `listB` as:

```
(declare-datatypes (T) ((list (nil) (cons (hd T) (tl list))))) 
(define-sort listA () (list A))
(define-sort listB () (list B))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
In the previous post, I used Z3 3.2 with *.smtc files.
Now I tried *.smt2 files with the new syntax and it works fine.